# Makefile linux - é possível restringir a compilação por máquina?

Tags: gcc, makefile

Olá

Tenho o seguinte cenário, várias máquinas compartilhadas em rede, e com diretórios visíveis entre si. Ocorreu de um desenvolvedor chamar a compilação do programa na máquina 1 , porém o programa só compila corretamente na máquina 2 (questões de ambiente e versões de SO/LIBS).

A minha dúvida é: existe alguma forma de no makefile colocar alguma checagem que impeça de realizar a compilação se não for a máquina 2?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Você pode setar uma variável na máquina correta, e no make:

```
ifndef MAQUINACORRETA
$(error "Máquina errada")
endif
```

Desta forma, a compilação só vai funcionar na máquina definida. Esta mesma lógica pode ser usada com variáveis existentes no OS:

```
ifeq ($(CARACTERISTICADAMAQUINA), valor)
 $(error "Máquina errada")
endif
```

Seja por IP, nome da estação, ou qualquer coisa que ache pertinente para o seu caso.

Note que pode fazer isso aqui para expandir algo do shell e usar no make:

```
$(shell echo $$OSTYPE)
```

Aplicado ao if:

```
ifeq ($(shell echo $$OSTYPE),ambientedesejado)
```

São exemplos, tem que adaptar para a característica que você considere adequada para o seu caso.

Comment: Entao neste caso existe entao uma variavel de ambiente que estara armazendo o nome da maquina ...e posso atrelar a ela. Valeu @Bacco vou procurar por formas de obter o nome da maquina e atribuir no make esta checagem

Comment: provavelmente é o caso de fazer $(shell COMANDOQUERETORNAONOME)